# Pass intents between fragments

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments

I want to pass an intent which from one tab to another. When I press a button in the first fragment I want it to direct me to the other fragment ( such as with activities). Is there another way to do this in fragments similar to    startActivity(new Intent(EntryTab.this, Journals.class)); ?  Below is my code and the startActivity line shows error. Help Please!

```
public class EntryTab extends Fragment{
    public static final String LOGTAG = "BALANCE";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries, container, false);
        Button save = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.entriesButton);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BalanceApp myapp= (BalanceApp) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                DataSource datasource = myapp.datasource;
                datasource.open();

                Log.i(LOGTAG,"inside tab entry");

                EditText amount = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.amount);
                int amt = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());

                 EditText debit = (EditText)ll.findViewById(R.id.debitText);
                 String dr = debit.getText().toString();

                 EditText credit = (EditText)ll.findViewById(R.id.creditText);
                 String cr = credit.getText().toString();

                 datasource.createEntry(dr, "DR", amt);
                 datasource.createEntry(cr, "CR", amt);

                 Cursor c=datasource.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM entries", null);
                 c.moveToFirst();
              //   Log.i(LOGTAG, dr + " " + amt + " " + cr );// the last row

                 Log.i(LOGTAG, c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) );// shows always the first row
                 datasource.close();

                 startActivity(new Intent(EntryTab.this, Journals.class)); // error: the constructor intent is undefined.

        }
    });
    return ll;      
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity can have many Fragments. In a fragment you can get the the activity by `getActivity()` method.

Moreover, to go from Activity A -> Activity B we use intents. 
Likewise, to go from Fragment A -> Fragment B, in Activity A, we use FragmentTransactions.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment f = new CustomFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also, use `addToBackStack()` method, in order to return to fragment A from fragment B on backpress.

Comment: Eclipse is showing me error on getSupportFragmentManager() function as undefined for the type class. Is this in a class which extends Fragments or something else? Thank you

Comment: Since fragments were introduced in Honycomb, you need to use compatibility packages in order for reverse compatibility on older devices. Please check whether you have android-support-v4.jar. It can be added by right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library.

Comment: I do have android-support-v4.jar. Do I need to extend or implement any other classes beside fragments? My class extends Fragment and I want to put use the FragmentTransaction inside the OnClick() method so that when the user clicks the button it jumps to the other tab. It still doesn't recognize getSupportFragmentManager() or CustomFragment().

Comment: Please check the ApiDemos, for detailed implementation.